# I want to validate phone number using regExp

Tags: flutter, dart, regexp-replace

The phone number should start with 0 followed by 6 or 7 and should contain 10 digits only

**Here are some sample phone numbers**

0754758644 ,0621165600

**Here is what I tried**

```
String pattern = r'(^(?:[0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
```

Comment: If it should contain ten digits why do you have `{10,12}`?

Answer (score 1):

this regex should work for you:

```dart
String pattern = r'(^0(6|7)\d{8}$)'
```

I limited the digits to 8, because the 0 and the 6/7 already take up two digits of the length. The `{8}` only limits the direct predecessor (the digits matcher `\d`).

find out more about this regex here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fnBoAU/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
String pattern = r'^(?:[+0][1-9])?[0-9]{10,12}$';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);

regExp.hasMatch(value)
```

or you can apply keyboardtype property to `textfield` or `textformfield` if you are not familiar with `regExp`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex pattern -

`String pattern = r'([0][6,7]\d{8})`

Comment: String pattern = r'([0][6,7]\d{8})' worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can match a zero, then either 6 or 7 using character class  followed by 8 digits.

For a match only, you can omit the capture group.

```
String pattern = r'^0[67]\d{8}$'
```